# How do I make my javascript function wait until after a fetch request returns before refreshing

Tags: javascript, python, html, jinja2

I am trying to make a basic note taking app using Flask as a backend and Jinja/Javascript for front end

when I click the "Add Note" button, a javascript function runs which uses a fetch post request to add the note in my database, and then refresh the page so it appears, I am assuming it doesn't work because the refresh doesn't wait until the fetch function to complete before reloading and nothing changes on the page

unfortunately it does not appear until after I refresh the page manually, any help would be appreciated as to how I can fix this!  (see code below)

HTML to list the notes and add a new one

```
    <div id="noteBox" class="scrollable-area" style="height: 60vh; overflow-y: auto;">
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="notes">
            {% for note in user.notes %}
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    {{ note.data }}
                    <button type="button" class="close" onClick="deleteNote({{ note.id }})">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
    <form>
        <textarea name="note" id="note" class="form-control"></textarea>
        <br>
        <div align="center">
            <button onClick="addNote()" class="btn btn-primary">Add Note</Button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Javascript function to add the note:

```
function addNote() {
    noteText = document.getElementById('note').value;
    fetch('/new-note', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({noteText: noteText}),
    }).then((_res) => {
        window.location.href = "/notes"
    });
}
```

Python backend to add the note into my database

```
@views.route('/new-note/', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def new_note():
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    noteText = data['noteText']
        
    new_note = Note(data=noteText, user_id=current_user.id)
    db.session.add(new_note)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify({})
```

Comment: Overall the code looks fine but could you 1) disable caching in the dev tools of the browser 2) try add a second `then()` to the fetch like this: `fetch(...).then((_res) => _res.json()).then(json =>  {window.location.href = "/notes"});` and see if either of them helps.